# How to handle a pretty URL in nginx that is not calling index.php from the root folder?

Tags: nginx, url

So if we did the following in the location block of the nginx.conf:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
```

That calls the index.php file from the root folder of the web server if we did something like https://www.example.com/john.

How would we write that so the index.php file it calls is the one in its parent folder?

For example: https://www.example.com/thisparent/john

That would use the index.php file from this location: https://www.example.com/thisparent/

This must work for any location of the web server where the pretty URL will be from the parent of the requested URL.

Comment: No, it will not call `index.php` from the `/thisparent/` unless it exists. If you want to only load `index.php` from the webroot folder, use `try_files $uri /index.php?$args;`

Comment: I want it to call index.php from /thisparent/.  I also want it to call the index.php from /thisparent/someotherparent/ if /thisparent/someotherparent is the pretty URL, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to internally redirect the URI path `/parent/child` to `/parent/index.php`, you need to compute the path to the parent directory `/parent`, since **nginx** does not provide a variable for the parent directory.

For example you can use:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    # PHP FASTCGI configuration
}
# Matches are eager, so the first group matches everything
# up to the last '/'. We capture it into the $parent named variable.
location ~ ^(?<parent>.*)/ {
    try_files $uri $parent/index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

The regular expression in the last location matches every possible URI path, so it has to be the last one in the `server` block and will take precedence over all normal prefix locations (except those with `^~` and exact locations).

A solution that is less aggressive is to use a named location as the fallback of the `try_files` directive:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri @parent_index;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    # PHP FASTCGI configuration
}

location @parent_index {
    rewrite ^(?<parent>.*)/ $parent/index.php;
}
```

Comment: ok, the first solution seems to work.  It does not if there is a / at the end however.  The 2nd solution makes the nginx server not want to start up at all.  We're getting close.

Comment: 1. If `/parent/` is a directory, the `index` directive is consulted to decide which file to serve. Add `index index.php` to your server block. 2. For the second solution try `nginx -t` to see, if there is a configuration error.

Comment: Thank you.  There was a duplicate location / error in the conf file.  I merged it with that block and it worked.  I will use the first solution since it feels more simple?  I will accept that /parent/ cannot be used as a pretty URL and the web server ill instead look for one of the index files.  Thanks again!

Comment: Whether `/parent/` is internally redirected to `/parent/index.php` by the `index` rule or your rewrite rule, it doesn't matter. Alternatively, you can remove `$uri/` from the `try_files` directive (as in the updated answer).

Comment: The `rewrite` rule appends the arguments automatically, whereas `try_files` doesn't. If you add `?$args` to the `rewrite` rule, you'll get your arguments doubled. Check with `rewrite_log on;`.

Answer (score -1):

Simple Solution I used for nginx, changing only one line.

In the location block change the try_files to:

```
location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php$is_args$query_string;
}
```

This worked perfect for me on nginx :)